# Mounting exFAT on Debian and use as Samba share - no write permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, exfat

I'm currently trying to mount an external exFAT drive on Debian 10 and use that as a Samba drive. Everything works and I can access the drive from my macOS machine. However, I'm unable to write anything to the drive - I only seem to have read permissions. As this is my first time working with exFAT I'm kind of out of ideas here - previously I would have played with the mount point permissions, but this obviously won't work with exFAT. So it must have to do with my way of mounting the drive or my Samba configuration. However, I previously had an HFS+ drive connected that worked flawlessly and which I've mounted exactly the same way.

This is the command I'm using to mount:

```
sudo mount -o rw,umask=0 -t exfat /dev/sda1 /media/wdelements/
```

This is my Samba configuration:

```
[External]
    comment = WD Elements 8TB HDD
    path = /media/wdelements
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    valid users = max
    writeable = yes
    public = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    write list = max
```

On the Debian host, a ls -l of the mount point shows full 777 permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 262144 Nov  4 19:41 wdelements
```

However, on the macOS Samba client, it shows:

```
drwx------  1 max   staff  16384  4 Nov 20:41 External
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think exFAT requires specifying a user or group for permissions when mounted.  If you look at the output of `mount`, do you see the exFAT mount using any options to specify a `uid` or `gid`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Thanks, but I've already tried using the `uid` and `gid` options, didn't work unfortunately. I fixed it now however, the solution was as simple as force reinstalling `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`. No idea what the problem was exactly, but the reinstall fixed it.